# Necessary package for compiling libX11

Tags: compiling, configure, x, source-code

I am currently trying to compile libX11 version 1.0.0 and during the configure process this error message shows up:

> checking for BIGREQS... configure: error: Package requirements (bigreqsproto) were not met:

I need to find the package (source package) that provides whatever the configure looks for it. The problem is that I am not being able to do so. The INSTALL and the README files does not indicate and the

```
configure --help
```

also does not. I looked for something with a name similar to "BIGREQS" on this link: https://www.x.org/releases/individual/lib/ but was not able to find anything remotely similar (at least I didn't note it)

So I would eagerly thanks anyone who knows what is the source package that I require to satisfy this dependency. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's [xorgproto](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto) (mostly definitions, not a "library" per se).

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, although your link worked for the configure part, it does not for the compiling part. This is the error message that appears: make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/libX11-1.0.3/src/util'
../src/util/makekeys < /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Xorgproto-2018.1/include/X11/keysymdef.h > ks_tables_h
/bin/bash: line 1: 12155 Floating point exception../src/util/makekeys < /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Xorgproto-2018.1/include/X11/keysymdef.h > ks_tables_h
make[1]: *** [ks_tables.h] Error 136

Comment: So I wonder if you do know where I can find an older version (it was xproto before, right?) that may not produce this error.

Comment: The link is for the source repository, which is as complete as you'll be able to find.